# Hot to print test summary after every test run

Tags: junit5

I am using Junit 5 and ant and i want to print junit test summary(number of tests passed/failed till now) after every test run.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is registering a test execution listener (see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-listeners) and updating your own summary.